# Assign values to a column using conditional on another column and row [Updated]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have few data frames that contains 'State' column with assigned values as a guide column, then 'City' column which its values depends on some conditions and two another columns, 'Feature' that varies according to the data frame and the fourth column is 'Rank', the rank of the 'Feature' column. Data['State', 'City', 'Feature', 'Feature rank']

```
dfs= [df_st_pop, df_st_l_ar, df_st_w_ar, df_st_t_ar]
for data in dfs:
    data.iloc[:,1]= [df.loc[df['State']== value, data.columns[1]].max() for value in data['State']]
    
    data.iloc[:,2]= [df.loc[df['State']== value, data.columns[2]].max() for value in data['State']]
    
    data.iloc[:,3]= data.iloc[:,2].rank(ascending=False, na_option='keep')
```

In the first line of the loop, i want to extract the city value instead of max feature value
,But i get the maximum of city name Alphabetically in each state.

```
data.iloc[:,1]= [df.loc[df['State']== value, data.columns[1]].max() for value in data['State']]
```

In order to see it in an easier way, I will write it in a simpler way

```
data.iloc[:,'City']= df.loc[df['State']== 'Alaska', 'City'].max()
```

For each value (state) in data['State'] i compare to value in df['State'] then take a maximum value from e.g. 'Land area km2, but actualy i want to extract not the maximum land value but the city the coresponding to that land value.

If i wrote the first line this way, i have error

```
data.iloc[:,1]= [df.loc[df['State']== value, data.columns[1]].max()['City'] for value in data['State']]
```

```
data.iloc[:,'City']= df.loc[df['State']== 'Alaska', 'Land area km2'].max()['City']
```

| index | State | city | Population | land area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alaska | Juneau | 32,255 | 2,704.00 |
| 1 | Alaska | Sitka | 8,458 | 2,870.10 |
| 2 | Kansas | Tribune | 1,182 | 778.2 |

For example in this case i want to extract "Sitka" instead of "2,870.10"

Rest of the code works perfectly. any suggestions how to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Hi guys, do you have maybe idea how can i solve this?
I'm thinking maybe to looping through each data frames, and somehow extract the 'City' value corresponding to max feature value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "state": ["Alaska", "Alaska", "Kansas"],
        "city": ["Juneau", "Sitka", "Tribune"],
        "population": ["32,255", "8,458", "1,182"],
        "land area": ["2,704.00", "2,870.10", "778.2"],
    }
)

other_df = pd.DataFrame({"state": ["Alaska", "Kansas", "Nebraska"]})
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Get a dataframe of cities with largest land area for each state
new_df = df.sort_values(by=["state", "land area"], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(
    subset="state", keep="first"
)

# Add city names to the other dataframe
for state in df["state"]:
    other_df.loc[other_df["state"] == state, "largest city"] = new_df.loc[
        new_df["state"] == state, "city"
    ].values
```

Then:

```py
print(other_df)
# Output

      state largest city
0    Alaska        Sitka
1    Kansas      Tribune
2  Nebraska          NaN
```